# How to get a list of used resources via python?

Tags: python

I am able to program simple things in Python but I am not very familiar with Python in Blender. So I would really like to know, if there is a simple way to list all the resources (textures, font files, etc) that are used in the project.?

Answer (score 1):

You should be check and use the API... in this case the data

https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.data.html

https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData

```
import bpy

d = bpy.data

## example for textures
textures =  d.textures

for texture in textures:
    print(texture.name)

#example for materials

materials = d.materials

for material in materials:
    print(material.name)
```